# Why can't I install projectile via use-package declaration?

Tags: use-package, package-repositories, projectile, install

I am watching a great YouTube series called [Emacs From Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INTu30BHZGk&list=PLEoMzSkcN8oPH1au7H6B7bBJ4ZO7BXjSZ&index=4) from [System Crafters](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAiiOTio8Yu69c3XnR7nQBQ)' YouTube channel. On episode [#4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INTu30BHZGk&list=PLEoMzSkcN8oPH1au7H6B7bBJ4ZO7BXjSZ&index=4), David Wilson talks about projectile.

His screen shows:

[image]

There is a pointer for the [source](https://github.com/daviwil/emacs-from-scratch/blob/82d24eea516e7799ead20cf068542e2b5ecb270e/init.el) on GitHub:

```lisp
(use-package projectile
  :diminish projectile-mode
  :config (projectile-mode)
  :custom ((projectile-completion-system 'ivy))
  :bind-keymap
  ("C-c p" . projectile-command-map)
  :init
  ;; NOTE: Set this to the folder where you keep your Git repos!
  (when (file-directory-p "~/Projects/Code")
    (setq projectile-project-search-path '("~/Projects/Code")))
  (setq projectile-switch-project-action #'projectile-dired))
```

Unfortunately, this **does not** work. After quitting Emacs, when I re-started it, I was expecting the installation to be successful. However, there is a message in the **Warning Buffer** indicating:

```lisp
Error (use-package): Failed to install projectile: https://melpa.org/packages/projectile-20220313.1334.el: Not found
```

This is weird because Projectile is listed on [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/projectile).

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: All the stuff about `projectile-project-search-path` is a red herring; you should remove it. The error message simply indicates that it tried to download the package and it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing `M-x package-refresh-contents` and re-starting Emacs, the previous error message was gone. Instead, there was this message:

```lisp
Leaving directory ‘/home/pedro/.emacs.d/elpa/projectile-20220419.1102’

Compiling file /home/pedro/.emacs.d/elpa/projectile-20220419.1102/projectile.el at Tue Apr 19 19:35:59 2022
Entering directory ‘/home/pedro/.emacs.d/elpa/projectile-20220419.1102/’

Compiling internal form(s) at Tue Apr 19 19:35:59 2022
Warning (bytecomp): ‘(let ((version (or (projectile--pkg-version) projectile-version))))’ is a malformed function
Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable ‘version’
```

After re-starting Emacs **again**, there was no message and Emacs had a normal start-up. Projectile seems to have been successfully installed. Not sure why it was necessary to refresh contents.

Comment: Look at the dates in the file name; you tried to download a file that was a month old and is, for whatever reason, no longer on the server.